# How can I select a region from a picture and blur the selected region and make it watermarked?

Tags: php, image, blur

I tried a lot but cannot find it out.. I have found watermarked script. But i did n't find a script where i can select a region from a picture and blur it..

I am using PHP Script for that.

Please help...

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to blur it, or would a watermark with a semi-transparent area be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using any of the various PHP image solutions out there (such as GD or ImageMagick) you should follow these steps:

First, create a duplicate image, and crop it to the are you wish to blur. Second, use some technique to do the blurring - this could be a literal blur, or be shrinking and expanding the image to create pixellation. Finally, overlay the blurred image back onto the original image in the correct location.

Comment: how do i overlay the blurred image?

Comment: imagecopy in GD will do it, this watermark tutorial may help you find the right method. http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=72317